telebot вывод фото и caption через переменную
Вот код :
photo = f"'{sheet["D1"].value}'"
caption = f"{sheet["B1"].value}"

print(photo)
print(caption)

bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, caption)
bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, photo=photo,caption=caption)

Терминал:
> 'https://sun9-36.userapi.com/gvl_MkX4aZJHqmRjE4lRlPOc8kwUClhe90y6MA/yONwF-t1eQ4.jpg'  
> test

(то есть всё ОК)
А бот выводит только test, значит срабатывает только send_message
По какай причине не работает send_photo?
P.s. просто вставить ссылку и caption в send_photo не вариант, так как они подгружаются из excel файла.

Если вы внимательно посмотрите на то, что вам выдает терминал
'https://sun9-36.userapi.com/gvl_MkX4aZJHqmRjE4lRlPOc8kwUClhe90y6MA/yONwF-t1eQ4.jpg'
то вы должны заметить, что ваш url обернут одинарными кавычками, которые вы зачем то добавляете при присваивании значения переменной photo. Замените
photo = f"'{sheet["D1"].value}'"
caption = f"{sheet["B1"].value}"

на
photo = sheet["D1"].value
caption = sheet["B1"].value

и все должно заработать

Спасибо, помогло

@Артем если вам помог мой ответ, то не забудьте принять его в качестве решения, нажав соответствующую кнопку слева от него. Спасибо
